# SQL Subquery removing leading zeros

Tags: sql-server

I created a function that returns a table. This table has two columns, PostalCode Nvarchar(255) and Passed Bit. The function is working perfectly when I call it directly like this:

```
SELECT PostalCode FROM fnPostalCodeFormatCheck('FR','68',1,2)
```

OUTPUT: `00068`

This function is so if a postal code needs leading zeros, as European postal codes do, it will put them on there.

Now when I use this function in a subquery with another table in order to review every postal code currently in my system, the leading zeros are removed. Example:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT PFC.PostalCode 
 FROM fnPostalCodeFormatCheck (RT.OriginCounty,RT.OriginZip,RT.CustomerID,RT.WorldRegionID) PFC
) [CorrectCode]
,RT.OriginCountry
,RT.OriginZip
,RT.CustomerID
,RT.WorldRegionID
FROM dbo.tr_tblRateTemplates RT
INNER JOIN dbo.tdw_qryPostalCodeRule PCRO
ON PCRO.WorldRegionID = RT.WorldRegionID
AND PCRO.ShipperID = RT.CustomerID
AND PCRO.CountryCode = RT.OriginCountry
WHERE RT.CustomerID=1
AND RT.WorldRegionID=2
AND OriginZip IS NOT NULL
AND OriginCountry <>'ES'
```

OUTPUT:

```
CorrectCode,OriginCountry,OriginZip,CustomerID,WorldRegionID
7884,       DK,           7884,     1,         2
68,         FR,           68,       1,         2
```

The datatype in the function is `nvarchar(255)`, so why is this value being changed?

Function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [fnPostalCodeFormatCheck]
(@Country AS NVARCHAR(255)
,@PostalCode AS NVARCHAR(255)
,@ShipperID AS INT
,@WorldRegionID AS int) 
RETURNS @rtnTable TABLE (PostalCode nvarchar(255), Passed BIT)
AS
BEGIN
    /*
    341 SCHED_JOB_ALCOA_EU@alcoa.com
    340 SCHED_JOB_ALCOA_NA@alcoa.com
    792 SCHED_JOB_ARCONIC_NA@arconic.com
    */

    --Local variables
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 CountryCode FROM dbo.tdw_qryPostalCodeRule
                    WHERE CountryCode=@Country
                    AND WorldRegionID=@WorldRegionID
                    AND ShipperID=@ShipperID)
        BEGIN
            --Just leave. There is nothing to evaluate
            INSERT INTO @rtnTable(PostalCode, Passed) Values( @PostalCode, 1)
            RETURN 
        END


    /*
    Column like '%-%-%' there cannot be two dashes
    Column not like '%[0-9]-[0-9]%' there must a be a digit to the left and right of the dash
    Column not like %[-/@#$%&*()%^a-zA-Z]% can not have these special characters and must have numbers only
    */

    DECLARE @Compare AS NVARCHAR(255) --this is the must have format
    DECLARE @Compare2 AS NVARCHAR(255) --This is the MUST NOT have format

    SELECT 
    @PostalCode=RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',(CASE WHEN LEN(@PostalCode)>Maximum THEN LEN(@PostalCode) ELSE Maximum END)) 
    + CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), @PostalCode), (CASE WHEN LEN(@PostalCode)>Maximum THEN LEN(@PostalCode) ELSE Maximum END))
    ,@Compare= 
    (CASE WHEN SpecialCharacter IS NOT NULL THEN  
            (CASE WHEN NumericOnly=1 THEN 
                REPLICATE('['+ SpecialCharacter + '0-9]' ,Maximum)
            ELSE 
                '%[' + SpecialCharacter + 'a-zA-Z0-9]' 
            END)  
        ELSE 
            (CASE WHEN NumericOnly=1 THEN 
                            REPLICATE('[0-9]',Maximum)
            ELSE 
                '' 
            END)
        END)
    ,@Compare2='%[' 
        + REPLACE('- /@#$%&*()%',ISNULL(SpecialCharacter,''),'')
        + (CASE WHEN NumericOnly=1 THEN '^a-zA-Z' ELSE '' END)
        + ']%'
    FROM dbo.tdw_qryPostalCodeRule
    WHERE CountryCode=@Country
    AND WorldRegionID=@WorldRegionID
    AND ShipperID=@ShipperID

    SET @Compare=dbo.fnCheckNvarcharValue(@Compare)
    SET @Compare2=dbo.fnCheckNvarcharValue(@Compare2)
    IF @Compare IS NOT NULL
        SET @Compare=@Compare + (CASE WHEN LEFT(@Compare,1)='%' THEN '%' ELSE '' END)

    --%[.,/-@#$&*()]%

    IF @Compare IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            IF @PostalCode COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN LIKE @Compare 
                BEGIN 
                    IF @Compare2 IS NULL 
                        BEGIN 
                            --'PASS' 
                            --SELECT 'Pass1',@Country,@PostalCode,@Compare,@Compare2,@UserID,@WorldRegionID,@ShipperID
                            INSERT INTO @rtnTable(PostalCode, Passed) Values( @PostalCode, 1)
                            RETURN 
                        END
                    ELSE
                        BEGIN
                            IF @PostalCode NOT LIKE @Compare2 
                                BEGIN
                                    --SELECT 'Pass 2',@Country,@PostalCode,@Compare,@Compare2,@UserID,@WorldRegionID,@ShipperID
                                    INSERT INTO @rtnTable(PostalCode, Passed) Values( @PostalCode, 1)
                                    RETURN 
                                END
                            ELSE
                                BEGIN
                                    --'FAILED'
                                    --SELECT 'Failed 1',@Country,@PostalCode,@Compare,@Compare2,@UserID,@WorldRegionID,@ShipperID
                                    INSERT INTO @rtnTable(PostalCode, Passed) Values( @PostalCode, 0)
                                    RETURN 
                                END
                        END
                END
            ELSE 
                BEGIN
                    --'FAIL' 
                    --SELECT 'Failed 2',@Country,@PostalCode,@Compare,@Compare2,@UserID,@WorldRegionID,@ShipperID
                    INSERT INTO @rtnTable(PostalCode, Passed) Values( @PostalCode, 0)
                    RETURN 
                END
                --,@PostalCode,@Compare,@Compare2
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            --SELECT 'PASS',@WorldRegionID,@ShipperID --We don't care
            --SELECT 'Pass 3',@Country,@PostalCode,@Compare,@Compare2,@UserID,@WorldRegionID,@ShipperID
            INSERT INTO @rtnTable(PostalCode, Passed) Values( @PostalCode, 1)
            RETURN
        END
    RETURN
END
```

The data for the rule table is like this:
CountryCode,Minimum,Maximum,NumericOnly,SpecialCharacter,WorldRegionID,ShipperID
FR  5   5   1   NULL    2   1

Which means France (FR) must have 5 characters, Numeric Only, No Special Characters Allowed, and the WorldRegion and Shipper for this rule.

Comment: This looks like it is a table valued function. Why not use cross apply instead of a subquery? As for the issue at hand there isn't enough information posted to recreate the issue so we can see what is going on. Can you post the table definitions, the function and some sample data?

Comment: Cross apply did not correct the issue. Here is the code for the function:

Comment: I wonder if there is some weird implicit cast to integer?

Comment: Ouch, that function makes me sad. Multi-statement table valued functions are generally even slower than scalar functions. But you are calling scalar functions inside there also. For a single row this probably isn't a huge deal but on a larger set this would crawl. But without being able to run this there isn't much chance anybody can help a lot. I think paparazzo is probably correct though.

Comment: I bet you don't have values in your table, which is used in first query).

Comment: a-man you are on to something. The data is there but parameters are not being passed.

Comment: UGH...... Typo. Thanks a-man.

Answer (score -1):

Since it appears you are looking for postal codes, they are always the same length. You could use code like this: `SELECT Right('00000' + [PostalCodeColumn], 5) AS PostCode`

Comment: Unfortunately, the leading zeros must follow a specific rule per shipper, world region, and Country. I would not know, without my function, how many zeroes to add.

Comment: That is only useful if you have American Zip Codes. Not all countries have the same format for postal codes.